Struggling with an epsilon delta proof.
The equation here is $xsin(1/x)$, and I need to prove the limits at 0 and $\pm \infty$. I've included my proof for 0, but I am struggling with infinity.
Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta = \epsilon$. Then, if $0<|x-0|<\delta$, $|xsin(1/x)| \leq |x| < \delta = \epsilon$. The first inequality is justified because $sin(1/x)$ is always between -1 and 1, so $|xsin(1/x)| \leq |x|$.

Hint: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\sin t}{t}$.

Do you know what you expect the limit at infinity to be?

A well known limit is $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$
Take $\epsilon>0$. By the above limit, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x|<\delta$, then $\left|\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}-1\right|<\epsilon$.
Pick $x_0=\frac{1}{\delta}$. If $x>x_0$ then $0<\frac{1}{x}<\delta$ and so $$|x\sin(1/x)-1|=\left|\dfrac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}-1\right|<\epsilon$$
This proves $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x\sin(1/x)=1$$
A symmetric argument taking $x_0=-\frac{1}{\delta}$ proves the limit at $-\infty$ is $1$ too.

Since $x\mapsto x\sin\frac1x$ is even, it is sufficient to deal with $x\to+\infty$. For this, simply use that for $u:=\frac1x>0$,
$$u-\frac{u^3}6<\sin u<u$$
hence
$$0<1-x\sin\frac1x<\frac1{6x^2},$$
which gives the requested direct and explicit $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\sin\frac1x=1$ (more precisely $1^-$):
$$\forall\epsilon>0,\quad\forall x>\frac1{\sqrt{6\epsilon}},\quad0<1-x\sin\frac1x<\epsilon.$$

Any objection motivating the downvote? In view of the accepted answer, I felt the need for a second one, corresponding more tightly to the question.

Not sure, I'm not the one who downvoted. Thank you for the second answer.
